# I tried to compare int and func and it gives an error

Tags: python

I tried to compare function and an integer but it gives an error
my game.py:

```
def game():
return 64
score = game()
with open("hiscore.txt" , "r") as f:
    hiscore = int(f.read)
if  hiscore<score :
    with open("hiscore.txt" , "r") as f:
        f.write(str(score))
```

my hiscore.txt

34

my console:

```
    hiscore = int(f.read)
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 
    'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: Please make sure that the [mcve] you show only replicate the problem you ask about, and that it doesn't have any unrelated errors (which your shown code have).

Comment: There are multiple typos here and other things that don't make any sense. You should try to follow a tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `()` after `f.read`.

```py
int(f.read())
```

Thanks for [ルカス](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13774631/%e3%83%ab%e3%82%ab%e3%82%b9) pointing out the wrong mode when writing to file in following code

```py
    with open("hiscore.txt" , "r") as f:
        f.write(str(score))
```

And you should change the mode for writing to file from `open("hiscore.txt" , "r")` to `"w"` or `"a"`

- `"r"` : read the contents of the file
- `"w"` : overwrite any existing content
- `"a"` : will append to the end of the line